# validation error messages are not set for associated record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Let's say we have the following context:

```
class Company
  belongs_to :address, validate: true
end

class Address
  validates :line1, presence: true
end

company = Company.new({ ... })
company.address = Address.new({ line1: '' })

company.save

puts company.errors[:address] # nothing
puts company.errors[:"address.line1"] # can't be blank
```

How can I make the validations errors to be set to the associated record and NOT to the owning record? This makes nested forms much more complicated because it's harder to reuse partials for these forms.

I actually need to have:

```
puts company.address.errors[:line1] # can't be blank
```

Answer (score 0):

[custom validation methods](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.13/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#custom-methods)

```
validate :check_address, :on => :create 

def check_address
  if self.address.line1.blank?
    errors.add(:line1, "Please fill line 1.")
  end
end
```

Comment: It's not truly necessary for a custom validator because the default behaviour does what I want. Validation errors to also be set to the associated record not only to owning record. Anyway, errors.add("Please fill line 1.") should be errors.add(:line1, "Please fill line 1.")

Answer (score 0):

Apparently it does work as intended. Just a hitch in my code made me think it doesn't. Feel ashamed now...